# Carregar json por demanda

Tags: angularjs

Pessoal sou iniciante em angular e estou fazendo uma pequena aplicação que consome um json, só que esse json é muito grande e eu queria carregar ele por demanda. Estou usando o conceito de SPA e uso tbm o ngRoute, eu só queria saber como posso resolver isso, ja estou fazendo teste com algumas buscas que fiz. Esse é o link da aplicação: http://guruapp.com.br/gurudev/#/

```
getCampanhas: function () {
  return $http.get('list.json');
},
```

Comment: Seu problema é com a carga ou com a visualização?

Answer (score 0):

Coloca um `| limitTo: qtde`  no ng-repeat e cria um botão para incrementar conforme a pessoa clica:

## controller

```
$scope.qtde = 20;

$scope.carregarMais = function () {
  $scope.qtde += 20;  
};

$scope.dados = dados;
```

Mas conforme for carregando, provavelmente ele vai ficar lento por ser muitos dados, por isso a paginação seria uma opção boa.

Comment: Olá Flavio, obrigado pela resposta. Realmente ele ainda fica muito lento, vou testar com a paginação. Obrigado por enquanto.